# Ubuntu One error

Tags: 12.04

```
CredentialsError
DBusException(dbus.String(u'Process /usr/lib/ubuntu-sso-client/ubuntu-sso-login exited with status 1'),)
```

I am totally new to Ubuntu. Inherited this computer and have never used this operating system before so I need some major help. this is just one error I am getting. I need to get in here to open a terminal, (so I am told). And then I need to search for a different problem there. Answers have been helpful here but I just keep inquiring a new problem as I go. So if anyone can help me even if it through chat I would appreciate it. HELP!!!!!! Michelle

Answer (score 0):

First, if you haven't already, run updates for the computer. Search in the dash for "update" and run the software updater program. This will install important updates for Ubuntu and could possibly fix this issue by itself.

After doing updates and restarting the computer, if the problem still persists remove Ubuntu One and re-install it. This web-page has step by step instructions for doing this: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+faq/778

**[note]:** The commands on that web-page will need to be run from the terminal. Dash -> search for "term" -> run terminal